# How to shorten natbib bibliography authors to et al

Tags: natbib, author-number, zotero, aastex

I'm using `aastex` (which uses `natbib`) with zotero (which outputs a bib file).

I've gone into the `natbib` `abbrvnat.bst` file and removed isbn, url & doi etc.

At the moment it reads:

> M. G. Abadi, B. Moore, and R. G. Bower. Monthly Notices of the Royal
>   Astronomical Society, 308 (4):947–954, 1999.

I need it to read:

> M. G. Abadi et al. Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society,
>   308 (4):947–954, 1999.

How do I force et al?
And how do I get rid of the double spacing between bibliographic items?

Answer (score 2):

Use `and others` after the name of the first Author. (This only works with BibTex) like:

```
Author="John Doe and others"
```

You will get:

```
J. Doe et al.
```